# How to get proper Twitter share count for a URL?

Tags: php, twitter

I am implementing a function to get Twitter count for my URL in PHP. I am trying to get count using:

```
  $json_string = file_get_contents("http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://themarketmogul.com/will-uber-ipo-in-2015");
  $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
  echo intval( $json['count'] );
```

This return 5 count but when I directly hit this URL in the browser then I get absolute count 6.

Please help me to find found proper count in PHP?

Comment: I get `5` if I directly hit this URL in the browser. Did you clear your browser's cache?

Comment: But i am using this script using cron setup on server

Comment: after removing cache in Mozilla browser still showing count 6

Comment: Federico, when you open http://themarketmogul.com/will-uber-ipo-in-2015 url in broswers you will see 6 no with twitter and when you hit http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://themarketmogul.com/will-uber-ipo-in-2015 will get same count but when you hit url in php you will see only 5 counts.

Comment: Is it possible that the results of twitter's API are cached?

Comment: i don't think so, because i am saving count in database on daily basis and count was on 2015-10-02 is 6 and now 2015-10-08 is 5

Comment: The JSON endpoint will be shut down November 20, 2015, so it's not an option anymore.

Right now, you will need to rely on the REST API Search endpoint – which are not the same as the JSON endpoint, as it just recognizes tweets from the last 7 days (https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-get-proper-twitter-share-count-for-a-url/53876/2). You can test the search endpoint with this tool here: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console

Answer (score -1):

The URL you are using is deprecated and won't work anymore.  Try http://opensharecount.com to get a URL that will work.